# what's the difference between object and primitive type when using matchers in EasyMock

Tags: easymock, matcher

```
//service to mock
public interface ServiceToMock {
public void operateDouble(Double dbValue);
public void operateCar(Car car);
}

//class under test
public class ClassUnderTest {
ServiceToMock service;  
public void operateDouble(Double dbValue){
    service.operateDouble(dbValue);
}   
public void operateObject(Car car){
    service.operateCar(car);
 }
}
```

//unit test class

```
@RunWith(EasyMockRunner.class)
public class TestEasyMockMatcherUnderTest {
@TestSubject
private final ClassUnderTest easyMockMatcherUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest();

@Mock
private ServiceToMock mock;

@Test
public void testOperateCar() {
    //record
    mock.operateCar(EasyMock.anyObject(Car.class));
    EasyMock.expectLastCall();

    // replay
    EasyMock.replay(mock);
    //matcher here...
    easyMockMatcherUnderTest.operateObject(EasyMock.anyObject(Car.class));
    //easyMockMatcherUnderTest.operateObject(new Car());

    // verify
    EasyMock.verify(mock);
}

@Test
public void testOperateDouble() {
    // record
    mock.operateDouble(EasyMock.anyDouble());
    EasyMock.expectLastCall();

    // replay
    EasyMock.replay(mock);
    easyMockMatcherUnderTest.operateDouble(EasyMock.anyDouble());

    // verify
    EasyMock.verify(mock);
 }
}
```

As the above code has shown, I intent to test two methods(operateDouble, operateObject). But things are kinda weird since everything runs fine in the operateDouble block while the compiler complaints an "Illegal state exception: 1 matchers expected, 2 recored." when runnig operateObject. And if commentting the method operateDouble out, the compaint goes away..So what is the difference between Double and my custom object Car, as the Double can also be considered as an object. And why does codes in operateObject runs well when commenting operateDouble method out?

Answer (score 0):

`EasyMock.anyDouble` and `EasyMock.anyObject` are not meant to be used in replay mode. They are used to setup your expectations in record mode.

Use this in your first test (`testOperateCar`):

```
easyMockMatcherUnderTest.operateObject(new Car());
```

and something like this in your second (`testOperateDouble`):

```
easyMockMatcherUnderTest.operateDouble(1.0);
```

---

By the way, you don't need to call `EasyMock.expectLastCall`. It is only useful if you expect a void method to be called multiple times, for example:

```
mock.operateCar(EasyMock.anyObject(Car.class));
EasyMock.expectLastCall().times(3);
```